# Html page break table with border (print)

Tags: html, page-break

I need need to use page break inside table rows. But the problem is when i use page break after row(tr), that row(tr) is drawing till end of page when printing.  Any ideas to fix this problem.

source:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1" >
       <thead>
         <tr><th>heading</th><th>heading 2</th></tr>
       </thead>
       <tfoot>
           <tr><td>footer 1</td><td>footer 2</td></tr>
       </tfoot>
       <tr>
           <td>x</td> <td>x1</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>x</td> <td>x2</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td></td> <td>
          <div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>x</td> <td>x3</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

screen shot:
first page,
[image: first page]
second page,
[image: second page]

Comment: add height style to your table using css

Comment: Have you found a solution? As a partial workaround we added a div with borders and fixed position to emulate the borders, but are unable to hide it on first and last pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason is `<div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>`

> always    - Always insert a page break after the element

For instance, with avoid value the issue is not observed on the print page.

[CSS page-break-after Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp)